# Applying T-Test to Every Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a dataframe (I'll call it PeerGroup) that has about 20 columns, each with a set of monthly returns for 20 different funds, dating back about a decade.  I'm trying to determine whether the average return over the past three years is statistically different from the mean for the track record as a whole.

Currently, using pandas, I can test the columns one at a time like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels as st
PeerGroup = pd.read_excel['File\Path.xlsx']
df['Fund1'] = st.ttest_ind(PeerGroup['Column1'], PeerGroup['Column1'].tail(36), equal_var='False')
```

However, if at all possible, I'd like to run the test on every column in the dataframe in one shot.  My best thought was to do something like this, but it turns into an IndexError.  Any thoughts?

```
df['All_Funds'] = PeerGroup[PeerGroup.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: st.ttest_ind(PeerGroup[x], PeerGroup[x].tail(36), equal_var='False'))
```

Comment: Not 100% sue why you're using `ttest_ind` for a two-sample test on a single column. It would have made sense to me to do it for each pari of columns, assuming there's some treatment to each column. Otherwise best use [`ttest_1samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method you're using here is feeding each of the columns of your dataset into your `lambda` function as an individual `Series`, but your `lambda` is written as though you're getting a column name instead.

To illustrate, here's a trivial example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
```

If we replace the method body with a `print`, to see what gets passed to the function:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: print(x))
<<< 0    1
    1    2
    2    3
    Name: a, dtype: int64
    0    4
    1    5
    2    6
    Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Your method call isn't working because you're indexing your `DataFrame` with a bunch of `Series` objects, each of which is a column of your dataset, which `pandas` doesn't know what to do with:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: df[x])
<<< [...]
<<< IndexError
```

(as a small aside, you *can* index a `DataFrame` with a `Series` of the correct "shape"; in this toy example try e.g. `df[pd.Series(['a'])]`)

Since you *already have* your column of interest, the solution is to simplify. This should work:

```
df['All_Funds'] = PeerGroup[PeerGroup.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: st.ttest_ind(x, x.tail(36), equal_var='False'))
```

Comment: Also, for readability, might I suggest swapping `x` for `fund` as your variable of choice?

Answer (score 0):

Statsmodels `ttest_ind` is computing the t-test in a vectorized way.

For example

```
>>> np.random.seed(123987)
>>> x = np.random.randn(50,5)
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> sm.stats.ttest_ind(x[:30], x[30:])
    (array([-0.95151202,  0.34686484, -1.85364701, -0.46793673,  0.06192139]), 
     array([ 0.34611141,  0.73020901,  0.06994078,  0.64194762,  0.95088256]), 48.0)
```

and to check with explicit loop

```
>>> np.array([sm.stats.ttest_ind(xi[:30], xi[30:])[:2] for xi in x.T]).T
array([[-0.95151202,  0.34686484, -1.85364701, -0.46793673,  0.06192139],
       [ 0.34611141,  0.73020901,  0.06994078,  0.64194762,  0.95088256]])
```

The same should work with a pandas DataFrame.

Note, if the two series that are compared in the t-test overlap, then the two samples are not independent. It is better to test whether the mean of the first part of the series is the same as the mean of the second part of the series.
This still assumes that the observations are approximately serially uncorrelated.

**edit**
It looks like the imported function refers to scipy.stats and not statsmodels, which uses a different keyword for the variance assumption.
Both work in a similar way (output reformatted to align numbers)

```
>>> sm.stats.ttest_ind(x[:30], x[30:], usevar='unequal')
    (array([-0.91734136,  0.36226976, -1.91402235, -0.45593946,  0.06075814]), 
     array([ 0.36512018,  0.71880355,  0.06199039,  0.6510849 ,  0.95186872]), 
     array([ 35.6978717 ,  46.16729003,  44.9965459 ,  37.18892135,  38.18591126]))

>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.ttest_ind(x[:30], x[30:], equal_var=False)
Ttest_indResult(
statistic=array([-0.91734136,  0.36226976, -1.91402235, -0.45593946,  0.06075814]), 
   pvalue=array([ 0.36512018,  0.71880355,  0.06199039,  0.6510849 ,  0.95186872]))
```